# Can someone explain the logic behind the code

Tags: python, python-3.x, for-loop

```
a=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7]
for a[-1] in a:
    print(a[-1])
```

For the above code  `a[-1]` is getting printed like mentioned below. Can someone please explain the logic behind this code. (Why is '6' getting printed twice)

Output: `1 2 3 4 5 6 6`

Comment: What do you expect it to do? Why are you using an element of the list as your loop variable? That's a recipe for disaster.

Comment: "Please explain this code" questions are generally too broad to be on topic here. See [How to handle "Explain how this ${code dump} works" questions](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/253894/how-to-handle-explain-how-this-code-dump-works-questions) on [meta].

Comment: Hi @Selcuk. My interviewer asked me to resolve this question in my interview. Actually, I'm not able to understand the logic .

Answer (score 2):

First, you should never change the element what you iterate while you loop.Just explain the logic, you should never write code like that.

your code actually eqaul to

```
a=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7]
for i in a:
    a[-1] = i
    print(a)#I add this help you understand
    print(a[-1])
```

result:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 1]
1
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 2]
2
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 3]
3
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 4]
4
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 5]
5
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 6]
6
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 6]
6
```

When you loop to `i == 6` first time,the last element of `a` change to `6`,so you print `6` twice.

I think what you actually need maybe this one:

code:

```
a=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7]
print(a[::-1])
```

result:

```
[7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1]
```

Answer (score 0):

From what I can tell, there will not really be a use case for this. But what the code seems to be doing is by printing the index [-2] twice and skipping the next number.

If the index is [-1] :
1 2 3 4 5 6 6 ( the index -2 is 6, so it's printed twice, the next number will be skipped, since there is no number after 7. It stops )

If the index is [-2] :
1 2 3 4 5 5 7 ( same logic here, index -3 is 5, so it's printed twice, the next number will then be skipped ( number 6 ), then the number 7 is printed )

If you need to manipulate the data, you should just do it in the loop and not in the for loop line.

Answer (score 0):

The value of `a[-1]` gets overwritten once you begin execution.

Run this to visualize each step:

```
a = [3,2,3,4,5,6,7]
for a[-1] in a:
  print(a[-1],a)
```

This will output the last element of your list, as well as the list itself like so:

```
3 [3,2,3,4,5,6,3] 
2 [3,2,3,4,5,6,2]
3 [3,2,3,4,5,6,3]
4 [3,2,3,4,5,6,4]
5 [3,2,3,4,5,6,5]
6 [3,2,3,4,5,6,6]
```

This shows that the `a[-1]` element has been updated before it even prints the first value.

So, once it finally reaches the end of the list, it basically overwrites its value with its own value.